# How to initialize one variable from another variable in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I want to initialize one variable with another variable in Vue js 
Here I want to initialize 'multiple' variable with 'select' variable

```
    <div id="myapp">
     <select v-model="select">
            <option selected>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select>
        <span>Selected {{select}}</span>
        <hr>
        <select v-model="multiple" multiple>
            <option selected>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
        </select>
        <span>Multiple Selected :{{ multiple | JSON}}</span>
    </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>   
<script>
    var vm=new Vue({
       el:'#myapp',
       data:{
                select:'B',
                multiple:select
        }
})
</script>`
```

Here I get an error like:
 **Uncaught ReferenceError: select is not defined**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access data properties like this in the `data()` method.

If you want to do this (though it seems a bit useless in this example), you will have to define a variable outside, and then reference it in `data()`

```
<script>
    var select = 'B'
    var vm=new Vue({
       el:'#myapp',
       data:{
                select: select,
                multiple:select
        }
})
</script>`
```